# C# first fit Algorithm output

Tags: c#, algorithm, for-loop, output

I've been given a homework assignment to code the first-fit algorithm, it's meant to assign a set number of jobs to a set number of memory blocks according to the first-Fit algorithm. So far I have the algorithm working and assigning jobs correctly; however, my problem is when my queued jobs are output to the console my loop doesn't iterate through all jobs being sent to queue, it just shows the initial job being sent to queue and its size until all jobs that were meant to be sent to queue have been iterated through.

This might be very simple but I can't seem to figure it out.... Anything else needed just ask and I can provide. Thank you.

```
public void firstFit(int counter, int JobIndex)
  {

 Counter = counter;
 jobIndex = JobIndex;

do {
        if (jobSize[jobIndex] > memorySize[Counter-1])
    {  
        Counter += 1;
    }
    else
    { 
    Console.Text += Environment.NewLine + "Job " + (jobIndex+1) + " of size " 
    + jobSize[jobIndex] + 
    " has been loaded into memory block:"
    + Counter;

    memorySize[Counter-1] = memorySize[Counter-1]-jobSize[jobIndex];

    Console.Text += Environment.NewLine + "The size of memory block " + Counter + " is now " + memorySize[Counter-1];

    Counter = 1;
    jobIndex += 1;
    }

}   while (Counter <= blocks && jobIndex < jobs);

for (int i = 0; i < jobs-jobIndex; i++ ){

jobQ = jobIndex;

if (jobQ < jobs)
{
    Console.Text += Environment.NewLine + "Job " + (jobQ+1) + " of size " + jobSize[jobQ] + " is sent to waiting queue!";


 }
}
```

> Job 1 of size 45 has been loaded into memory block:1 The size of
>   memory block 1 is now 16
>
> Job 2 of size 1230 has been loaded into memory block:2 The size of
>   memory block 2 is now 410
>
> Job 3 of size 325 has been loaded into memory block:2 The size of
>   memory block 2 is now 85
>
> Job 4 of size 303 has been loaded into memory block:3 The size of
>   memory block 3 is now 131
>
> Job 5 of size 1178 has been loaded into memory block:5 The size of
>   memory block 5 is now 393
>
> Job 6 of size 1276 has been loaded into memory block:6 The size of
>   memory block 6 is now 426
>
> Job 7 of size 965 has been loaded into memory block:7 The size of
>   memory block 7 is now 322
>
> Job 8 of size 537 is sent to waiting queue!
>
> Job 8 of size 537 is sent to waiting queue!
>
> Job 8 of size 537 is sent to waiting queue!

Comment: Some code would help...

Comment: can you provide some code example?

Comment: Shot in the dark...Is this showing what happens for 10 jobs?  As in, the last two "Job 8 ..." lines are actually supposed to be `Job 9` and `Job 10`?  Check your code that iterates through the jobs in the queue and make sure your control variable is being incremented, and that you are using that control variable to grab the right job.  Also, in debugging, check that your queue actually has Job 9 and Job 10.  Could be you inserted Job 8 three times.

Comment: Yup, supposed to be 10 jobs, last 2 jobs should be job 9 and job 10, with their own sizes.... For some reason this has had me stuck since yesterday >.< Might just be looking at it wrong where i've been staring at the code for so long xD

Answer (score 1):

You have this code at the end:

```
for (int i = 0; i < jobs-jobIndex; i++ )
{
    jobQ = jobIndex;
    if (jobQ < jobs)
    {
        Console.Text += Environment.NewLine + "Job " + (jobQ+1) + " of size " +
            jobSize[jobQ] + " is sent to waiting queue!";
    }
}
```

The value of `jobQ` is the same each time through the loop, so of course it's going to print the same thing every time. Is it possible you meant the first line in the loop to read:

```
jobQ = jobIndex + i;
```

??

Comment: that was pretty much the issue, outputting the same value every time.... I ended up fixing the issue a slightly different way to what you put, but couldn't answer my own question within 8 hours of asking it.

Answer (score 0):

Sorted. Thank you Ryan for pointing me in the right direction. Problem was i wasn't trying to get the job number of all the values that needed to go into the Queue, i was just getting the job number of jobQ+1, which would always be the same job, the first job that didn't fit. The same for my jobSize.

Here's the bit of code i had to change:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < jobs-jobIndex; i++ ){
 jobQ = jobIndex;


if (jobQ < jobs)
 {
    Console.Text += Environment.NewLine + "Job " + (jobQ+(i+1)) + " of size " +  
    jobSize[jobQ+i]) + " is sent to waiting queue!";


 }
}
```